# Creating .exe using pkg library out of next js build

Tags: next.js, exe

I am trying to create an .exe file out of nextjs build.I am using the pkg library for this .the command is "pkg . -t node16-win-x64"

This is throwing error "Error! Property 'bin' does not exist in package.json".Can i know the correct way to create the executable file.

next : v12.1.6
node : v16.16.0

Comment: Next js also has a server, you must create .exe only for the frontend part.